# Draw great circles in one direction

Tags: r, maps, gis, great-circle, geosphere

I am using the `R Geosphere package` to draw great circles connecting pairs of GIS coordinates between the US an India.

As far as I can tell, the package calculates the closest distance between the two points on the geosphere and then plots the great circle in that direction (I think this direction is technically called the `azimuth`?).

However, I want all the great circles going in one direction in my plot -- across the Atlantic Ocean, not the Pacific.

Is there some way to get them going one way (best) or to suppress the great circles that are not going in the right direction (less ideal)?

Comment: Perhaps this would be a good question for http://gis.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: In any case it would be more tempting to help if you provide a [minimal, self contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)